# generate excel in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to generate excel with enabling auto-filter option.For that I have create one template excel file by enabling auto-filter option but when I write something into that template excel file auto-filter option disabled again.

Is there any solution to create excel file by enabling auto-filter option.

Comment: As for now, you won't have success with POI, the feature is not implemented yet... see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35125

Comment: jexcelapi won't help you either, see http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/changehistory.html - they tried to, but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for (and you don't really describe how you write the file today). "create excel file by enabling auto-filter option" doesn't really make sense to me.

There is the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) that I have used for generating excel files and it works pretty well. Is that was you are using to write excel files today?

Comment: yes i have use apache poi.I want to enable auto filter option (Data --> Filter --> AutoFilter) in excel sheet when excel opened.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at Andy Khan's JExcel.  I think it's the best library out there for working with Excel in Java.